# CSS media not working on a set of devices

Tags: css, media, device, responsiveness

I have written media queries for a project i am working on. The whole devices on my chrome are working fine on samsung, pixel and I-phones but not working on Infinix and tecno phones. These are media queries i used:

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 384px)
@media (max-width: 768px)
```

All the devices on my chrome device emulator is working fine but when i check with mt infinix and tecno phones, it doesnt work fine. Check the screenshots [for tecno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPFQP.jpg) [for infinix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lanQl.jpg) [for samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJyTG.jpg) [for iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EBRb.jpg)
The navigation is showing well in the last two but not in the first two

Comment: Can you confirm the screen resolutions as well? If you are trying to see the same result in all different phones, then resolutions should be the same. Can you share the resolutions of all these phones that you are testing on?

Answer (score -1):

Give these breakpoints a try. They are used in Bootstrap

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
}
```

It is best practice to have no gaps in your @media because there are so many devices you cannot test on.

Do not think in devices, but think in "@media ranges". If the webpage is looking well in each @media range then it looks fine on all devices.

Answer (score -1):

As checked in your screenshots,

**Problem seems not in media query, But with cross browser support of your css codes.**

Did you flexbox or any other css3 methods ? if yes, then add css autoprefixer codes for browser fallbacks.

You can also use some online tool like pleeease.io to get browser autoprefixer codes.

Answer (score -1):

I didnt use flexbox or grid initially. I used them and the problem was solved.